# org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.java file located in Jboss EAP 6.3

Tags: jboss, catalina

I tried to run simple Web APP in JBoss EAP 6.3 and from the log and  I saw

```
DEBUG [org.apache.catalina.realm] (http-/127.0.0.1:8080-1)   User data constraint has no restrictions
```

This logging message is from org.apache.catalina.realm.RealmBase.java

I would like to know, where does this file located in EAP 6.3? Which jar file?

I am running Windows 7 and the Jboss is installed under C:\EAP-6.3.0

Thanks
David

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is located in 
C:\EAP-6.3.0\jboss-eap-6.3\modules\system\layers\base\org\jboss\as\web\main\jbossweb-7.4.8.Final-redhat-4.jar

Thanks
David